# Minimum Path cover in a Directed Acyclic Graph

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, graphs, weighted-graphs, hamiltonian-path

Given a weighted directed acyclic graph $G=(V,D,W)$ and a set of arcs $D'$ of $D$, where the weights of $W$ are on the vertices. The problem is to partition $G$ into a minimum number of vertex-disjoint paths that cover all the vertices of $G$ subject to the constraints that:

1. the weight of each path is at most $k$.
2. each path should include at least one edge of $D'$.

What is the complexity of this problem?

Comment: Why do you tag hamiltonian-path?

Comment: because the minimum path cover problem is a generalization of the hamiltonian path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer shows this problem is NP-hard. Further research is needed to determine whether it belongs to APX or it is APX-hard.

Let $G$ be a complete directed acyclic graph, i.e., you can name the vertices $1,2,\ldots,n$ and there is an edge $(i,j)$ for all $i<j$. Let $D'=D$, and $k$ is equal to half of the sum of the weights of all vertices. Now there exist 2 vertex-disjoint paths satisfying your conditions if and only if the weights can be partitioned into two subsets both with sum $k$, which is exactly the [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem). Hence, your problem is NP-hard.

Comment: if $k$ is a constant, the problem becomes polynomial? because searching a minimum number of vertex disjoint paths that cover an acyclic graph can be solved in polynomial time by transforming it in a matching problem.

Comment: I don't know. Maybe. It requires further thinking. And your problem is not only the problem of searching vertex disjoint path.

Comment: yes, each path should also pass by at least one of the edges of $D'$